# Set shape color programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using keyboard view where i have custom xml shape thath i can set specific buttons a color here is my **shape xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <solid android:color="#80B3B3B3"/> 
  <corners android:bottomRightRadius="2dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="2dp" android:topRightRadius="2dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Then I overwrite my `onDraw` method for **Keyboard View:**

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        for (Key key : keys) {            
            Drawable dr = (Drawable)this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.keyshape);               
            dr.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
            dr.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to allow that user set this color of Shape any idea how can I set this before drawing?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should do a custom view that you want to set and extend it (TextView or Button w/e I will write sample as extending View) since you are not able to edit shape xml programmatically, you will create it as a whole.

Override needed behaviours and constructors for your View. Now you will create a method setGradientColors that take two colours as int values (bottom and top gradient colors). You can modify it for setting radius for rounded corners as well.

```
public class GradientView extends View{

    public GradientView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public GradientView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public GradientView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void setGradientColors(int bottomColor, int topColor) {
        GradientDrawable gradient = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[] {bottomColor, topColor});
        gradient.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        gradient.setCornerRadius(10.f);
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(gradient);
    }

}
```

You are going to use this new view and set shape programmatically as:

```
GradientView view = (GradientView) findViewById(R.id.customView);
// bottom color - top color order
view.setGradientColors(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"), Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
```

If you need further assistance and full explanation about basics, I have achieved this in my project by following this **[Link](http://bnotions.com/efficient-use-of-drawables-to-develop-a-dynamic-ui-on-android/)**

Hope it is going to help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change shape colour pro grammatically either you have to create new shape with different colour or you can use :

```
imageView.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#BBBDBF"), Mode.MULTIPLY);
imageview.invalidate();
```

it will multiply the given colour code with your image background and will show effect of colour changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want change only the colors on the shape from the xml drawable, I changed your onDraw a little to do it.
It will be a [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) if you define it in xml with `<shape>` tag.

```
        Drawable dr = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.keyshape);
        if (dr instanceof GradientDrawable) {
            GradientDrawable gradientDr = (GradientDrawable) dr;
            gradientDr.setBounds(key.x, key.y, key.x + key.width, key.y + key.height);
            gradientDr.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            gradientDr.draw(canvas);
        }
```